# Perl: WWW:Mechanize, getting Facebook profile image?

Tags: facebook, perl, api, www-mechanize

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#USE DECLARATIONS
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Term::ANSIColor;

#VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $img;
my $title;
my $pic_page;
my $url;
my $count;
my @links;

#CONNECT TO FACEBOOK
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/';
$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent_alias( 'Linux Mozilla' );
$mech->get( $url );
$title = $mech->title();

#LOGIN FORM
print "Connected to Facebook.\n";
print "Logging in...";
$mech->form_id("login_form");
$mech->field("email",'my@email.com');
$mech->field("pass",'mypass');
$mech->click();
print "done!\n";

#NAVIGATE TO USER PAGE
$mech->get("https://www.facebook.com/some.profile1234");
$title = $mech->title();
print "Finding $title 's profile pictue...\n";

#FIND PROFILE PICTURE
$img = $mech->find_image(url_regex => qr/s160x160/, );
print $img->url();
downloadImage($img->url(),$mech->title().".jpg");

sub downloadImage
{
    my $local_file_name = $_[1];
    my $b = WWW::Mechanize->new;
    print "Downloading: $_[1]...";
    $b->get( $_[0], ":content_file" => $local_file_name );
    print "done!\n";
}
```

With this code I just want to download profile picture of a given person (#NAVIGATE TO USER PAGE) and save it. However, I get an error saying essentially that no images could be found! WHYYY? (I am using the $mech->find_image(url_regex => qr/s160x160/,) to find the image on the profile page.)

Comment: is this image really exists?

Comment: The correct way to do this is via the [Facebook Graph](https://metacpan.org/module/Facebook::Graph) API.

Comment: This will almost certainly break some rule in the Facebook TOS.

Answer (score 0):

You are using new instance of Mechanize in your downloadImage sub. And **this instance is not authorized by Facebook**.

Try this:

```
downloadImage($img->url(),$mech->clone() );

sub downloadImage
{
    my $mech = $_[1];
    print "Downloading: $_[1]...";
    $mech->get( $_[0], ":content_file" => $mech->title() . ".jpg" );
    print "done!\n";
}
```